# Grid View selected index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid which contains  a edit button . When i click the edit button and debug it does not hit to the selected index change event  . There  are no build errors

code behind the grid

```
public void btnModemDetailsEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isEdit = true;
}

protected void gridModemDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridModemDetails.DataKeys[GridModemDetails.SelectedIndex].Values["gridModemDetails_SelectedIndexChanged"].ToString());
}

<asp:GridView ID="GridModemDetails" runat="server" Width="435px" 
              DataKeyNames="ModemId" AllowPaging="True"
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridModemDetails_SelectedIndexChanged"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" Visible="True" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnModemDetailsEdit" 
                                AccessibleHeaderText="Edit" 
                                ButtonType="Button" 
                                Text="Edit" 
                                HeaderText="Edit" 
                                runat="server" 
                                OnClick="btnModemDetailsEdit_Click"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GridView`'s `SelectedIndexChanged` event is tied to the `RowCommand` event.

The simple way to get the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to fire is to use the `AutoGenerateSelectButton` property of the `GridView`, like this:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
```

This will add a button to each row with the text `Select` and when clicked, the `SelectedIndexChange` event will fire.

---

In the case of your edit button, you can use the `CommandField` in the grid view markup, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now in your code-behind, you can handle the `RowCommand` event, like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit") 
    {
        // Get the actual row
        GridViewRow theGridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex);

        // Do something with grid view row here
    }
}
```